# Cannot find module 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Browserify is throwing this error once I try to use Promises.

Cannot find module 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' in

I've tried node versions 10.15.3 and 12.0.0.

Why is it looking for it in the source folder and not node_modules?

Here's my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "2.6.5"
    }

  ]];
  const plugins = [];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ehrsWAR",
  "version": "1.10.15",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {},
  "browserslist": [
    "> 5%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "Firefox > 20",
    "ie >= 9"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-streamify": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to include "@babel/transform-runtime" in your plugins under babel config. And include @babel/plugin-transform-runtime in your package.json. I was getting the same error and this resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I thought useBuiltIns and core-js was supposed to handle that. But I added it and got a new error.

Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault'

Comment: I removed the corejs entry from my babel config. While Babel gave a warning for it, it did compile. So it seems to not like the corejs for some reason.

Comment: Installing @babel/polyfill fixed it. I was under the impression that was deprecated in favor of core-js, guess I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As suggested by @kombat, installing @babel/polyfill fixed it.